# Debian USB install cannot find hard drives

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, debian

I'm attempting to install Debian wheezy onto a new server box I just built, however the auto-detection for the platter drives and SSDs (using SATA 6gbps) does not seem to pull up anything. In fact, the only storage that the detection can find is the USB stick that I'm attempting to install with in the first place. I'm using UNetbootin to put files onto the drive.

Some basic info:

Hardware:

- 2x Samsung 840 EVO 120GB (Part#: MZ-7TE120BW)
- 4x Seagate Barracuda 3TB (Part#: ST3000DM001)

`/dev` contains:

- `sda`
- `sda1` -> thumb drive

Hand-typed output of `df -h` is:

```
ID  ->  Size  ->  Mount point
------------------------------
none -> 790.0M -> /run
devtmpfs -> 3.9G -> /dev
/dev/sda1 -> 7.3G -> /cdrom
```

And the contents of `fstab`:

```
none    /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0   0
none    /run    tmpfs   nosuid.size=10%,mode=755    0   0
none    /proc   proc    defaults    0   0
none    /sys    sysfs   noauto  0   0
```

[Here is a dmesg of the system, with an additional flash drive attached to save the output](http://pastebin.com/Q4uXrcc6).

LSPCI output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cb1
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cba
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8cad
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 8ca0
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c90 (rev d0)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c96 (rev d0)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8c98 (rev d0)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 8ca6
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8cc4
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 8ca2
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b1 (rev 73)
```

Any possible insight or attempted IT here would be greatly appreciated, I'm a bit lost at this point on how to get all the storage detected.

Comment: What motherboard are you using ? Also as a sidenote, you don't need to use unetbootin to put debian install media onto a USB stick. You can simply `dd` the iso file onto the USB stick. `win32dd` is a windows equivalent.

Comment: @Lawrence Using [Gigabyte GA-Z97N-WIFI](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4993#ov). And thanks for the tip.

Comment: As an update, attempting to install using other distributions does not work as well (no drives detected still), however the motherboard's built-in integration with Intel's "hardware" RAID can detect the drives just fine.

Comment: Do you have the "hardware" RAID activated ? Or are you using the drives normally ?

Comment: @Lawrence it is disabled as I was planning on doing a software raid instead.

Comment: Can you also get a `lspci` output pastebinned too ?

Comment: I don't see any IDE/SATA/SAS/HDD Controller of any sort popping up. That would be why it can't see the drives. Debian isn't recognising the drive controller.

Comment: @Lawrence so at least we're at the diagnostic stage, now how do I go about solving it so debian will recognize the controller?

Comment: This seems counter-intuitive, but what happens if you **enable** the hardware raid controller ?

Comment: @Lawrence go put down an answer, it seems when the raid software was disabled it also disabled the SATA controller, which I fixed in the bios :)

Comment: FYI you've a BIOS update (F4) available which says "Improve SSD Performance", it may interests you: http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4993&dl=1&RWD=0#bios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the Hardware RAID and it may also enable the SATA controller.

Some motherboards have the 2 interlinked so disabling one will also disable the other.

Answer (score 0):

If no device nodes appear in `/dev` for your storage drives that possibly means the kernel didn't recognize them. Try figuring out which modules you need to load(Google for your hardware model and support in Linux).

EDIT: It would be good to post your `$ dmesg` output from the beginning of the installation or from the live system.

Comment: I don't see an easy way of copying over the `dmesg` output from the installation (I can pipe it to a file, but not sure how to persist that file and retrieve it on windows since I cannot finish the installation). As for part IDs, I added them to the question since I couldn't really find any helpful information looking them up.

Comment: Your problem is kind of strange so the `dmesg` output is really necessary to see what's happening and why the kernel didn't map the drives into the `/dev` tree. Try using a second USB drive. mount it, format it to a portable fs(e.g. fat32) then save the file on it.

Comment: I can't see anything referring to your HDDs and SSDs(but I don't understand every dmesg message so maybe it's my fault)... Have you tried any other distro or OS? Note that i've also found this sentence at the specifications tab on your motherboard's page: "Due to different Linux support condition provided by chipset vendors, please download Linux driver from chipset vendors' website or 3rd party website."