# Debian installer can’t find laptop ssd and I can’t change the mode to RAID in the BIOS

Tags: ssd, debian, bios, raid

I am trying to usb install debian 10 to my hp laptop. However, it is not finding the laptop’s ssd, only the usb drive. I am not experienced with installing operating systems, but I read at [Debian USB install cannot find hard drives](https://superuser.com/questions/784189/debian-usb-install-cannot-find-hard-drives) that I should enable hardware RAID. In the BIOS “aptio setup utility” there is no option to change it.

Comment: Actually most of the times is the opposite. "RAID" and "Intel RST" drive modes in modern motherboards are not compatible. The recommendation is to always use AHCI. Enabling hardware RAID as mentioned in the linked question is applicable to server grade machines with real hardware RAID controllers.

Comment: What course of action should I take to get the debian installer to see the ssd then?

Comment: Check your UEFI ("BIOS") settings to find something related to what I commented above.

Comment: It said just non-raid

Comment: So, you're saying that the options are "RAID" or "non-RAID"? If so choose the latter, of course. Keep in mind, if dual-booting, the other OS may not boot after the change. If installing Linux alone it doesn't matter of coursed.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that there was no option it just said non-raid